# Is it possible to set a "threshold" for a scikit-learn ensemble classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a [VotingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) comprised of 200 individual SVM classifiers. By default, this classifier uses majority-rule voting. I want to set a custom threshold - where a classification is only made if 60% or more of the SVM classifiers are the same.

If 59% of SVM classifiers have the same classification, I do not want the ensemble model to make a classification.

I don't see a parameter to do this for the `VotingClassifier` object, but I assume it must be possible somewhere in scikit-learn. Is there a different ensemble class I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the methods you get at the end of the page, the simplest solution is to use the transform methods:

```
def transform(self, X):
        """Return class labels or probabilities for X for each estimator.
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
            Training vectors, where n_samples is the number of samples and
            n_features is the number of features.
        Returns
        -------
        If `voting='soft'` and `flatten_transform=True`:
          array-like = (n_classifiers, n_samples * n_classes)
          otherwise array-like = (n_classifiers, n_samples, n_classes)
            Class probabilities calculated by each classifier.
        If `voting='hard'`:
          array-like = [n_samples, n_classifiers]
            Class labels predicted by each classifier.
        """
```

just do a simple function that will get the sum for a line divided by the number of SVM and apply your Threshold:

```
if(ratio>threshold):
     return 1
elif(ratio<(1-threshold)):
     return 0
else:
     #we don't make the prediction
     return -1
```